# Wordpress callback function to list custom post type posts

Tags: php, wordpress, callback

I'm trying to list all posts of the custom post type "post_consultants".

How would I edit the following to automatically return post IDs for key and value, and consultant name (which is the post title) for description?

```
function my_consultants_prefill() {
  return array(
      array("key"=>1, "value"=>1, "description"=>"Consultant #1"),
      array("key"=>2, "value"=>2, "description"=>"Consultant #2"),
  );
}
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post_consultants',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        $result[] = array("key"=>$post->ID, "value"=>$post->ID, "description"=>"Consultant #1");
    <?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not sure that will help though.

It needs to be a function that I can call in a plug in field

Comment: No luck, I get the following message:


`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/webdevsp/public_html/blueskiescareers/wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/framework/Form/Element/Multi.php on line 62
$result[] = array("key"=>$post->ID, "value"=>$post->ID, "description"=>"Consultant #1"); $result[] = array("key"=>$post->ID, "value"=>$post->ID, "description"=>"Consultant #1"); $result[] = array("key"=>$post->ID, "value"=>$post->ID, "description"=>"Consultant #1"); $result[] = array("key"=>$post->ID, "value"=>$post->ID, "description"=>"Consultant #1"); `